# Vlookup vba automatisation

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, vlookup

I'm a beginner in VBA programmation, I want to create a button to help me search the price of a product from `column A` of `sheet1` and to search for the price of that product from `sheet2`, `column D` of the same workbook.

The `vlookup` formula I use is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;sheet2!A2:G712;4)
```

My issue is that I have more than 100000 products and I want to use a button to simplify the process.

Answer (score 0):

Change your top row formula to `=VLOOKUP(A2;sheet2!$A$2:$G$712;4)`, select the cell you enetered the formula into, and then drag the formula down by using the little square in the bottom right hand corner of the cell you entered the formula into.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it entirely in VBA, you can autofill using

```
Dim source As Range("A1")
Dim destination As Range("A1:A10")
source.AutoFill Destination:=destination
```

This will autofill from A1 to A10, as an example. You can also specify the autofill type with Type:

```
Dim source As Range("A1")
Dim destination As Range("A1:A10")
source.AutoFill Destination:=destination Type:=xlFillLinearTrend
```

The default type is `xlFillDefault`, which tries to find a pattern automatically and use the according fill type. Other types can be looked up [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlautofilltype-enumeration-excel).